# Import JavaScript module if exists

Tags: javascript

I have a directory of JavaScript files each acting as a plugin for my app. Now in the parent directory I have a main `js` file in which I import those plugins. But I want to check if the plugin exists before importing them. Is it possible to do that? The directory structure looks like this:

```
main.js
plugins/
    plugin_1.js
    plugin_2.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dyncamic `import` function in js which returns a promise which is rejected if the file does not exist :

```js
import { a, b } from 'plugins/plugin_1.js'
```

becomes

```js
try {
  const { a, b } = await import('plugins/plugin_1.js')
} catch (error) {
  // the file does not exist or couldn't be loaded
}
```

Notice the use of top level await here, you should so mark your script tag inside of your html `async`.

Hope it helped !